# Select certain columns programmatically from Excel spreadsheet based on a common identifier

Tags: c#, sql, excel, datagridview

After importing an excel sheet over to a windows form via a data-grid view. I need to select various columns and send them to the database. How do you select various columns based on a common identifier?

Excel sheet

[image]

As you can see in the image, I would like to select the names based on the identifier. Is there any way to approach this?

Comment: @shikiko..mark my answer if it is solving your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This will give list of names based on identifier

```
                var mainDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>()
        {
            {"Group1", new Dictionary<string, List<string>>{{"A", new List<string> {"bob", "steve", "greg"}}}},
            {"Group2", new Dictionary<string, List<string>>{{"B", new List<string> {"tom", "thomas", "justin", "lee"}}}},
            {"Group3", new Dictionary<string, List<string>>{{"C", new List<string> { "dustin", "rick" }}}}
        };

        var namesA = from m in mainDict where m.Value.ContainsKey("A") select m.Value.Values.First();
        var namesB = from m in mainDict where m.Value.ContainsKey("B") select m.Value.Values.First();
        var namesC = from m in mainDict where m.Value.ContainsKey("C") select m.Value.Values.First();
```

Comment: is there anyway i can get the group from the excel sheet instead of hardcoding them out?

Comment: @shikiko..I gave you example on how to query the data...its not hardcoding..you can load excel data in dictionary of dictionary and query it..or you can use linqtoexcel....https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel